# Switching from HTTP to HTTPS automatically in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, https, global-asax

How to switch from HTTP to HTTPS automatically in ASP.NET?

Also no need to do same thing in Local connection

Answer (score 0):

Lets start:

Open Global.asax code finde **Application_BeginRequest**,change it like this:

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection.Equals(false) && HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal.Equals(false))
            {
                Response.Redirect("https://" + Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"] + HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
            }
        }
```

Bingo!

Comment: This doesn't work in IIS8 - is there a fix for this?